# Java loop, confused on how to add up total loops

Tags: java, loops, netbeans, switch-statement

I'm not providing the whole code just the main section. The code is looped based on how many workers I enter and is repeatedly asking questions such as age, name, id, and status. I want the program to run how many times someone enters an offsite worker, and how many times someone enters they are on-site. Since I won't provide the full-code, let's say the loop is about 6 times and is asking the questions above to each of the 6 workers.

```
int offsite = 0, onsite = 0;
          switch (status) {
case "ResidentFullTime":
    System.out.println("pay: " + 3465 ) ; 
    onsite++;
    break;
case "ResidentPartTime":
    System.out.println("pay : " + (hour * 3456) ) ; 
    onsite++;
    break;
case "NonResident":
    System.out.println("pay : " + (hours * 233) ) ; 
    offsite++;
  break;
}
```

I tried using `System.out.println("Total Off Site" + offsite);
            System.out.println("Total on site " + onsite );`

but it didn't give me the total amount it just counted as I went but I wanted it to total up in the end. 
What I want the code output look like

```
There are in total 3 off site wokers
There are in total 3 on site wokers
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you move `int offsite = 0, onsite = 0;` outside the loop?